# I'm getting "invalid sql display size" when trying to fetch rows from SQL Server via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

So I decided to hash the password field in my Users table and on my login page I'm needing to check to make sure they've entered the correct password. So here's where I get the password from the table:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM Users where Username='".$user."'");

$passhash = "";

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

       $passhash = $row['PwHash'];    
}
```

This works fine. However when I try to hash the password they typed in like this:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "select HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', '".$pw."') as PwHash");

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $typedpasshash = $row['PwHash'];
 }
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Invalid sql_display_size in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 39

which points to the `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. I've looked up some ways to try to handle it, but nothing works. The `PwHash` field in my table is a `binary(64)` datatype. Any ideas?

Comment: try using `sqlsrv_fetch` instead of `sqlsrv_fetch_array` and see if the error goes away

Comment: I did that but sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0) pulls back "Resource id #7" for some reason. the error does go away though.

Comment: Don't use SHA for password hashing. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: And you've probably also got a [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Comment: this site walked me though it: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/

Comment: ok. i was unaware of the password_hash() and password_verify() functions. I'm new to this. Also, I plan to prevent the SQL injection, I just want to get the backbone of the site down first.

Comment: _"this site walked me though it"_ That's bad advice. It is not secure.

Comment: So Alex, what datatype should I use for the password_hash() function?